# averageifs if date in cell is less than date in next cell

Tags: excel, date, average

I need to find the running average of a list of numbers for a specific product within a date range and only if the date in one row is less than the date of the cell beneath it.  Currently my formula looks like this:

`=AVERAGEIFS(D:D,A:A,">="&A2,A:A,"<="&A2+9,B:B,B2,????)`

where D:D is my list of numbers, B:B is my product, and A:A contains dates  (sometimes the same date repeats successively in a column). Everything works until I try add the last criteria (????) that only shows averages if one cell is less than the cell that follows it.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

`A           B       C   D   E       F
1/2/2015    FFW04   1   215 137.33  182.82
1/5/2015    FFW04   50  219 137.33  165.00
1/5/2015    FFW04   2   219 137.33  165.00
1/6/2015    FFW04   2   179 137.33  127.73
1/7/2015    FFW04   0   177 137.33  122.60
1/7/2015    FFW04   1   177 137.33  122.60
1/7/2015    FFW04   2   177 137.33  122.60
1/7/2015    FFW04   50  177 137.33  122.60
1/7/2015    FFW04   5   177 137.33  122.60
1/7/2015    FFW04   2   177 137.33  122.60
1/9/2015    FFW04   100 117 137.33  41.00
1/14/2015   FFW04   5   19  137.33  12.25
1/15/2015   FFW04   10  14  137.33  10.00
1/15/2015   FFW04   2   14  137.33  10.00
1/20/2015   FFW04   2   2   137.33  2.00
1/5/2015    FFEW015 5   44  36.78   42.14
1/5/2015    FFEW015 5   44  36.78   42.14
1/6/2015    FFEW015 6   52  36.78   34.71
1/7/2015    FFEW015 1   46  36.78   31.83
1/7/2015    FFEW015 9   46  36.78   31.83
1/9/2015    FFEW015 9   36  36.78   24.75
1/14/2015   FFEW015 9   27  36.78   21.00
1/15/2015   FFEW015 9   18  36.78   18.00
1/15/2015   FFEW015 9   18  36.78   18.00`

A = date, B = Product, C = Orders 
D = total orders per 9 day period`=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,">="&A2,A:A,"<="&A2+9,B:B,B2)`
E = Average of total orders   `=AVERAGEIFS(D:D,B:B,B2)`
F = Average of total orders  `=AVERAGEIFS(D:D,A:A,">="&A2,A:A,"<="&A2+9,B:B,B2)`

Neither E nor F is quite what I am looking for because of the multiple returns per day in D.  (I have removed columns from the original to simplify this sample)

Comment: What cell will this formula be typed in?

Comment: K2 - and will fill down from there

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `">="&B2` and `">="&B2+9`?

Comment: This was supposed to return the average total orders for nine day periods per product.  I used a similar formula to find total orders per 9 day period per product but I see the problem is that some days may have one order others may have multiple while others have none.  Since I am working with rolling totals and rolling averages I need to find a way to return average orders for 9 day periods per product without including repeat totals for the same day in my average.

Comment: I don't understand why you would care if the date is less than the date in the cell beneath it if you are simply going for a 9 day rolling average. Seeing a sample of your data would be incredibly helpful. Can't you just sort your data so the dates are always in asc/desc order?

Comment: I might be using the wrong approach with the cell dates; there might be a better way, but keep in mind that I am looking for an average of total orders for multiple 9 day periods and orders per day vary.  I will include a a sample of what I am working with.  This comes from a massive spreadsheet with thousands of products, which is why I am wanting to have all my data running and rolling rather than just working with each product separately.

Comment: I edited my original post to include a simplified sample of my data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a helper column. In cell E2 use the formula `=A2=A1` and drag it down. Then in Columns F and G you can put your averageifs() formulas with an additional criteria. See below:

Column F:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(D:D,B:B,B2,E:E,"FALSE")
```

Column G:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(D:D,A:A,">="&A2,A:A,"<="&A2+9,B:B,B2,E:E,"FALSE")
```

Comment: Did you mean `D2=D1`?   I think that `A2=A1` would suit my purposes even better in case for some reason successive dates would have the same total orders.  Thanks!

Comment: I actually meant `=B2=B1`, but realize that is not correct. Changed it to `=A2=A1`.